# how to grab data from hidden gridview aspx to put in html table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

so i used a sqldatasource to make a gridview of data in the front end of my aspx page. i just want to get the data of a certain column to put in area of my page.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ticket #" HeaderText="Ticket #" SortExpression="Ticket #" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=--;Initial Catalog=--;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=--" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="tickets_GET" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hD" DefaultValue="0" Name="cd" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i want to use the ticket number field in the text in my html but i cannot use itemtemplate

so i try but no luck

```
   <div>ticket number : <asp:Label id="ticket" runat ="server" text='<%# Eval("Ticket #")%>'></div>
```

Comment: Is your data source really returning column with name "Ticket #"? Also, what does "no luck" exactly mean - an error, no output, anything else?

Comment: yea ? and nothing shows up no error